# Rails - Simple Search from Railscast Not Displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search, rails-activerecord, railscasts

i've been following the railscast tutorial on how to create a simple search form,
for some odd reason, whenever I search the URL changes and the server log shows that it searches for the post, in this case an ad, but it doesnt display it.

My Ad Controller.

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ad, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /ads
  # GET /ads.json
  def index
    @ads = Ad.search(params[:search])
    @ads_small = Ad.where(:size => "small").order('created_at DESC')
    @ads_medium = Ad.where(:size => "medium").order('created_at DESC')
    @ads_featured = Ad.where(:size => "featured").order('created_at DESC')

  end

  # GET /ads/1
  # GET /ads/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /ads/new
  def new
    @ad = Ad.new
  end

  # GET /ads/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /ads
  # POST /ads.json
  def create
    @ad = Ad.new(ad_params)
    @ad.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @ad.save
        format.html { redirect_to @ad, notice: 'Ad was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @ad }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @ad.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /ads/1
  # PATCH/PUT /ads/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @ad.update(ad_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @ad, notice: 'Ad was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @ad.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /ads/1
  # DELETE /ads/1.json
  def destroy
      @ad.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to ads_url }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_ad
      @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def ad_params
      params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :url, :preview, :location, :size, :info, :search)
    end
end
```

My Ad Model

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :title, :url, :preview, :size, :location, :info
    belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :preview, :default_url => "missing.jpg", :styles => { :medium => "125x125^", :featured => "250x250^", :showpg => "400x400^" }, :convert_options => {:medium => "-gravity center -extent 125x125", :featured => "-gravity center -extent 250x250", :showpg => "-gravity center -extent 400x400"}

  validates :title, length: { maximum: 35 }
  validates :url, length: { maximum: 40 }

  def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "#{search}"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
end
```

My Ad Index View

```
 <%= form_tag ads_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p class="search_f">
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :class => "glow_f" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => "submit" %>
<% end %>

<% @ads.each do |ad| %>
<% if ad.size == "featured" %>
  <div class="adspace_grid_f">
    <div class="pic_sec_f">
      <%= image_tag ad.preview.url(:featured) %>
    </div>
    <div class="text_info_f">
      <span class="bold"><%= link_to ad.title, ad, :class => "title" %></span></br>
      <p><%= truncate(ad.info, length: 90) %></p>
      <span class="bold"><%= ad.location %></span></br>
      <span class="bold"><%= ad.url %></span>

    </div>
    <% if can? :destroy, ad %>
      <%= link_to 'Delete', ad, :method => :delete, :class => "delete" %> 
    <% end %>
  </div> 
<% end %>
<% if ad.size == "medium" %>
  <div class="adspace_grid">
    <div class="pic_sec">
      <%= image_tag ad.preview.url(:medium) %>
    </div>
    <div class="text_info">
      <span class="bold"><%= link_to ad.title, ad, :class => "title" %></span></br>
      <p><%= truncate(ad.info, length: 60) %></p>
      <span class="bold"><%= ad.location %></span></br>
      <span class="bold"><%= ad.url %></span>

    </div>
    <% if can? :destroy, ad %>
      <%= link_to 'Delete', ad, :method => :delete, :class => "delete" %> 
    <% end %>
  </div> 
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `ad.size` for the ads that qualify for your search.  If the size isn't "featured" or "medium" it looks like your view will ignore it since the only if-conditions are for `ad.size == "featured"` and `ad.size == "medium"`.

If you want to see what is being found by the search, include this line above the `<% @ads.each do |ad| %>` line:

```
<% @ads.inspect %>
```

Also, `@ads_small`, `@ads_medium`, and `@ads_featured` don't appear to be used anywhere.  Are those for a future purpose?

Comment: Ah, okay, it seems to have been a problem with cap sensitivity in my search, anyways that you know of removing the capital sensitivity?

Comment: Oh, and the @ads_small/medium/featured do appear in my code, the view I posted above is only a snippet of it.

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL, use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE` in your `search` method.

Comment: And if you want to search for that value anywhere within the data, you can use `%`, with something like `['title ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%"]`.